# How to reference an Outlook sub-sub-subfolder?

Tags: vba, outlook

I've gotten a module that scans a subfolder for emails with pdf attachments and saves them to a specific folder on my shared hard drive.

I want the macro to scan a subfolder within a subfolder within a subfolder.

I can't figure out how to arrange `Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("Palo Park")` to specify my sub-sub-subfolder.

Under my Inbox, my subfolders look like this:
[image]

It is this "Subm from Arch" subfolder I want to scan for attachments.

```
Sub SaveAttachmentsToFolder()
' This Outlook macro checks a named subfolder in the Outlook Inbox
' (here the "Sales Reports" folder) for messages with attached
' files of a specific type (here file with an "xls" extension)
' and saves them to disk. Saved files are timestamped. The user
' can choose to view the saved files in Windows Explorer.
' NOTE: make sure the specified subfolder and save folder exist
' before running the macro.
On Error GoTo SaveAttachmentsToFolder_err
' Declare variables
Dim ns As NameSpace
Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim Item As Object
Dim Atmt As Attachment
Dim FileName As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim varResponse As VbMsgBoxResult
Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("Palo Park")
i = 0
' Check subfolder for messages and exit of none found
If SubFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "There are no messages in the Subm from Arch folder.", vbInformation, _
           "Nothing Found"
    Exit Sub
End If
' Check each message for attachments
For Each Item In SubFolder.Items
    For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
    ' Check filename of each attachment and save if it has "pdf" extension
        If Right(Atmt.FileName, 3) = "pdf" Then
        ' This path must exist! Change folder name as necessary.
            FileName = "S:\1- Job Files - Active\# 3034 - BHP Palo Park\07 - Submittals\Submittals from Architect\" & _
                Atmt.FileName
            Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next Atmt
Next Item
' Show summary message
If i > 0 Then
    varResponse = MsgBox("I found " & i & " attached files." _
    & vbCrLf & "I have saved them into the S:\1- Job Files - Active\# 3034 - BHP Palo Park\07 - Submittals\Submittals from Architect folder." _
    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Would you like to view the files now?" _
    , vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Finished!")
' Open Windows Explorer to display saved files if user chooses
    If varResponse = vbYes Then
        Shell "Explorer.exe /e,S:\1- Job Files - Active\# 3034 - BHP Palo Park\07 - Submittals\Submittals from Architect\", vbNormalFocus
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "I didn't find any attached files in your mail.", vbInformation, "Finished!"
End If
' Clear memory
SaveAttachmentsToFolder_exit:
Set Atmt = Nothing
Set Item = Nothing
Set ns = Nothing
Exit Sub
' Handle Errors
SaveAttachmentsToFolder_err:
MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
    & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
    & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: GetAttachments" _
    & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
    & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
    , vbCritical, "Error!"
Resume SaveAttachmentsToFolder_exit
End Sub
```

Comment: Pointer: **1.** Main sub to start recursive Sub on a root folder. **2.** Recursive Sub takes folder as argument, process all items in the folder (by calling another sub to extract pdf attachements), finally a loop to call *2* again for all it's Sub-folders.

Comment: Are you trying to go thru all the subfolders and its subfolders of `Palo Park` folder to save its attachments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("Palo Park")
Set SubSubFolder = SubFolder.Folders("Submittals")
Set SubSubSubFolder = SubSubFolder.Folders("Subm from Arch")
```

or (simpler)

```
Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("Palo Park").Folders("Submittals").Folders("Subm from Arch")
```

Comment: Thank you Tim! I used your simpler version and it works great. I appreciate your help.